# "certificate verify failed" despite setting CACERT.PEM environment variable in Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, openssl

I have set the environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE correctly -- here's cmd output for set:

> SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem

Here's a link to what I have in my cacert.pem: [cacert.pem](http://pastebin.com/3QEP8HjZ)

Here's the cmd windows output running irb:

```
C:\Users\anon\prog\workspace>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'open-uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> open ('https://www.youtube.com')
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:75:in `timeout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:313:in `open_http'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:724:in `buffer_open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: On Windows, I believe you need to `set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem` in your script. Calling `set` without arguments will print your environment, like `printenv` on most Linux. Also see [Setting and getting windows environment variables from the command prompt](http://superuser.com/q/79612) on Super User.

Comment: I did in fact set that SSL_CERT_FILE in the windows environment variables, and I was just showing the output of the set command in order to clarify that the environment variable was, in fact, set. Help me, please, Mr. Wizard!